# Proof of Frisch-Waugh-Lovell Theorem

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear, projection

In the book I am currently reading, they propose the following proof:

$\hat{Y} = X_1 \hat{\beta}_1 + X_2 \hat{\beta}_2$

Now because $M_1 = I - P_1$, we can always derive a formula for $X_2$:

$X_2 = P_1 X_2 + M_1 X_2$

and plug that in:
$\hat{Y} = X_1 \hat{\beta}_1 + (P_1 X_2 + M_1 X_2) \hat{\beta}_2$

and expand:
$\hat{Y} = X_1 \hat{\beta}_1 + P_1 X_2 \hat{\beta}_2 + M_1 X_2 \hat{\beta}_2$

if we now define $\hat{\gamma} = \hat{\beta}_1 + (X_1' X_1)^{-1} X_1' X_2 \hat{\beta}_2$ we can write:

$\hat{Y} = X_1 \hat{\gamma} + M_1 X_2 \hat{\beta}_2$

So far so good. But now comes a step, that I just don't understand. The next thing they come up with is the following:

$Y = M_1 X_2 \hat{\beta}_2 + u$

They are referring to that a regression on an orthogonal set of regressors can be done on each set at a time while still getting the coefficients from the joint regression.

What does that exactly mean and how does it help to rearrange the equation? I think it would help if anyone could show me the steps inbetween the second last and the last equation.

See for example: [https://uh.edu/~bsorense/FrischWaugh.pdf](https://uh.edu/%7Ebsorense/FrischWaugh.pdf)

Comment: It's indeed due to being "__orthogonal__" but can you provide a snap of your book or cite your source?

Comment: Sure, here is a short article, basically doing the same thing as in the book: https://uh.edu/~bsorense/FrischWaugh.pdf

Comment: Hm. I think Wikipedia does a better derivation than this note, which I am not too much at ease with even with the claim that this is "projection based". Any approach involves orthogonal projection operator.

Comment: FWL only says: $\mathbf M_1\mathbf Y=\mathbf M_1\mathbf X_2\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}_2}+ \mathbf M_1\mathbf u. $ Partition $\mathbf X^\top\mathbf X$ and find $\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}_1$ and substitute it to the other normal equation and use the projection operators.

Comment: Do you guys have any suggestion, where I can find a (simple) full proof for it? Should I turn to wikipedia or is there another source, which you can recommend?

Comment: The derivation is simple if you can visualize it geometrically. Wikipedia has some sources referenced but I followed Greene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just leaving a note to hopefully give this theorem some intuitive content.  We can kind of visualize what is going on in the case of two regressors.  Let $X$ be an $n \times 2$ matrix.

The columns as two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but for visualization purposes we will imagine them in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Call them $\vec{x}_1$ and $\vec{x}_2$ .  They span a plane.  Our response variable $\vec{y}$ we will picture as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which does not live on the plane.

Then the OLS regression $\hat{y}$ is the orthogonal projection of $\hat{y}$ onto the plane spanned by $\vec{x}_1$ and $\vec{x}_2$.

This theorem is saying that you can obtain the same $\hat{y}$ by

1. Projecting $\vec{y}$ orthogonally onto the span of $\vec{x}_1$ to get $\hat{y}_1$.
2. Projecting $\vec{x}_2$ onto the orthogonal compliment of $\vec{x}_1$ to get $\vec{x}_2'$.
3. Projecting $\vec{y} - \vec{y}_1$ onto the span of $\vec{x}_2'$ to get $\hat{y}_2$.
4. Then $\hat{y} = \hat{y}_1 + \hat{y}_2$.

If you draw the pictures this should be geometrically clear.  You are basically just forming a new basis for the plane whose first basis vector is $\vec{x}_1$, and whose second basis vector is the projection of $\vec{x}_2$ onto the orthogonal compliment of $\vec{x}_1$. The matrix algebra just generalizes this idea.  Hopefully this makes the content of the theorem more intuitive!

Answer (score 2):

The document you shared includes a little typo where it say "$M_1X_2$ is orthogonal to $X_2$". This is incorrect. $M_1X_2$ is not orthogonal to $X_2$ since $$X_2'M_1X_2$$ is the sum of squared of residuals from regressing $X_2$ on $X_1$.

Indeed, $M_1X_2$ is orthogonal to $X_1$ and this is the key element leading to a correct proof: note that $$X_1'M_1X_2=0$$
which implies that if put the term $X_1\widehat{\gamma}_1$ in the error term ($u$), with the regressor being $M_1X_2$, then OLS delivers $\widehat{\beta}_2$ when regressing $Y$ on $M_1X_2$ (with the error term including $X_1$).

Comment: Yes. The note indeed contained error and more importantly the derivation was unnecessarily made wordy without presenting any new thing. Anyway +1.